# How to enforce that a NuGet package must be installed into a specific .NET version

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I have created a package from a project set to .NET 4.5.2.  I can install this package into a new project that is .NET 4.5.2 just fine.  But if I install it into a project that is .NET 4.5.1, the installation *appears* to work (no error messages, and the package shows up under the Installed list) but my Assembly isn't now added as a reference to the project. I find that lack of any error message very odd.

I have tried adding the following to my NuSpec:

```
<frameworkAssemblies>
        <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.5.2" />
</frameworkAssemblies>
```

which I would have thought would work, but it makes no difference.  I am *guessing* that all this does is ensure that you do have that assembly in the GAC, *not*, it appears, that you are installing into a 4.5.2 project.  Is that correct? And what can I do instead?